# Get hash from file while you copy or move it

Tags: bash, shell, hashsum, tee, pv

Say I copy a file with `pv`, is there any way to also get any hash, like `md5`, `sha1`, etc without having to read origin twice? It has to work with big files or block devices.

Example command which does not work as expected:

```
pv /dev/sda1 | tee md5sum > /mnt/backups/sda.backup
```

Answer (score 3):

`... | tee md5sum > outputfile` doesn't work because `tee` takes a filename as argument, the command would create a file called `md5sum`. Instead, you could replace the filename with a process substitution (in Bash/ksh/zsh):

```
... | tee >(md5sum) > outputfile
```

or just flip the logic so that you give the destination filename to `tee`, and can then pipe its stdout to `md5sum`:

```
... | tee outputfile | md5sum
```

Also, you may want to use e.g. `sha256sum` or `sha512sum` instead, given how MD5 is known to be rather broken.

Comment: Thanks that's perfect.